# Java Quartz Refiring from Exception

Tags: java, quartz

We have a requirement, where we need to re-fire the Quartz job, upto 5 times max, if the job faces a Java Exception.

But when we try to call either of these methods, from the main Exception

```
JobExecutionException je;
je.refireImmediately();
je.setRefireImmediately(true);
```

the re-firing does not happen.

Quartz version been used is 1.7.3

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you need to rethrow your newly created exception.  This code works in 2.1.6, but in 1.X you might need to increment/store the refire count manually in the JobDataMap.

```
try {
    whatever();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Retry this job up to 5 times.
    if (context.getRefireCount() < 4) {
        logger.warn("job_failure attempt={}", context.getRefireCount());
        throw new JobExecutionException(e, true);
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```